# What is difference between Init and update function of knockout js custom binding

Tags: knockout.js

i like to know what is difference between Init and update function of knockout js custom binding ?

when we should write code inside init function and when we should go for update function of knockout js custom binding.

i go through knockout js doc but still my understanding for knockout js custom binding is not very clear to me.

i just wonder if someone help me to understand when we go for init and when we go for update with example.

here i am point out some code which not very clear and their intention.

### Code for Init function

```
<div data-bind="allowBindings: true">
    <!-- This will display Replacement, because bindings are applied -->
    <div data-bind="text: 'Replacement'">Original</div>
</div>

<div data-bind="allowBindings: false">
    <!-- This will display Original, because bindings are not applied -->
    <div data-bind="text: 'Replacement'">Original</div>
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.allowBindings = {
    init: function(elem, valueAccessor) {
        // Let bindings proceed as normal *only if* my value is false
        var shouldAllowBindings = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: !shouldAllowBindings };
    }
};
```

### Code for Update function

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someText, customBinding: someText">

ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       console.log( JSON.stringify(value) );       
    }
}

ko.applyBindings({
    someText: ko.observable("inital value")
});
```

Comment: Init triggers only once, when the binding is first bound. Update triggers once initially, and after that every time the value observable is changed (if you bound an observable to it, else it will never update). So in the first code block, the only thing Knockout needs to know is whether descendent bindings should be allowed. Because bindings are applied only once, the init function is used. In the second sample, we want to log the value **everytime it changes** (here, the value of someText), so the update binding should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) clearly states where these these methods are used:

> Knockout will call your **init** function once for each DOM element
> that you use the binding on. There are two main uses for init:
>
> - To set any initial state for the DOM element
> - To register any event handlers so that, for example, when the user clicks on or modifies the DOM element, you can change the state of the
>   associated observable
>
> Knockout will call the **update** callback initially when the binding
> is applied to an element and track any dependencies
> (observables/computeds) that you access. When any of these
> dependencies change, the update callback will be called once again.

Short answer is `init` function is called once when the binding is initialized, and `update` function is called every time when there is an update in the value bound. You can find examples in the link above, I don't think it is worth copying them here.

Comment: u said "Knockout will call your init function once for each DOM element " just see my first example where custom binding name is allowBindings. there two div used the allowBindings.....does it means init will be called twice for two div?

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `return { controlsDescendantBindings: !shouldAllowBindings };` ? what is controlsDescendantBindings....is it any ko built-in function or keyword ?

Comment: Please read all 4 articles in Knockout documentation about creating custom bindings, it should answer most of your questions. Specifically `controlsDescendantBindings` is described in [this article](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)

Comment: @dotnetom He doesn't read the documentation, he just asks 1100 questions on stackoverflow